# ion-button [disabled] not working unless another element is changed after reCAPTCHA validation

Tags: html, angular, forms, ionic-framework, recaptcha

It seems as though input verification is working properly (i.e. regex, name size, selection) as the "Submit" button is selectable as soon as any other input is updated (and valid) AND the captcha has been completed before the change. However, when the captcha is done last, the ion-button is still disabled, despite all inputs being valid, including the captcha. It's as if the ion-button [disable] property doesn't refresh when the recaptcha is a success, and it only refreshes when any of the other inputs are updated.

HTML:

```
<form #testForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
            <ion-radio-group value="{{selectTest}}" [(ngModel)]="selectTest" name="selectTest" mode="md">
                <ion-radio value="Test1" (click)="selectTest='test1'"></ion-radio>
                <ion-label>Test1</ion-label>
                <ion-radio value="Test2" (click)="selectTest='test1'"></ion-radio>
                <ion-label>Test2</ion-label><br>
            </ion-radio-group>
            <ion-item class="cust_input" lines="none">
                <ion-input
                    [(ngModel)]="firstName"
                    name="firstName">
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="input" lines="none">
                <ion-label position="floating" class="required">Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input
                    [(ngModel)]="email"
                    placeholder="ex: email@yahoo.com"
                    name="email">
                </ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <div id="capcha_element" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="getResponseCapcha" data-expired-callback="getExpiredResponse" [attr.data-sitekey]="siteKey"></div>
            <ion-button 
                mode="ios"
                type="submit"
                [disabled]="firstName.trim().length<1
                || !emailRegex.test(email)
                || selectTest==''
                || !captchaSuccess"
            >
                Submit
            </ion-button>
        </form>
```

TS:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
export class TestPage{
  constructor(
      public captchaSuccess: boolean = false;
  )
  ngOnInit() {
      this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        recaptcha: ['', Validators.required]
      });
      grecaptcha.render('capcha_element', {
        'sitekey': this.siteKey,
      });
      window['getResponseCapcha'] = this.getResponseCapcha.bind(this);
      window['getExpiredResponse'] = this.getExpiredResponse.bind(this);
  }
  getResponseCapcha(captchaResponse: string) {
      this.captchaSuccess = true;
  }
  getExpiredResponse() {
    this.captchaSuccess = false;
  }
```

Any ideas why this is occurring?

Answer (score -1):

Try using ngZone:

In constructor: `public ngZone: NgZone`

Don't forget to `import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';`

Then:

```
getResponseCapcha(captchaResponse: string) {
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.captchaSuccess = true);
}
```

This will force the update on the UI.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment. This line of code:

`getResponseCapcha(captchaResponse: string) {
    this.ngZone.run(() => this.captchaSuccess = true);
}`

produces an "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError" in my code. Any ideas on how to fix it?